# How can I spread the NLTK computation to multiple cores?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a bigram analysis over the Enron data corpus:

```
for message in messages.find():
    sentences = [ s for s in nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(message["body"]) ]
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = words + PunktWordTokenizer().tokenize(sentence)
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
print finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 20)
```

However, when I watch "top", I see that one core is being saturated while the others are idle. Is there any way for me to distribute the computation to all the other cores (this is on the Google Compute Engine)

top output:

```
    Tasks: 117 total,   2 running, 115 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    %Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu4  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu5  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu6  :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    %Cpu7  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    KiB Mem:   7369132 total,  5303352 used,  2065780 free,    68752 buffers
    KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,  4747800 cached
```

Comment: Your code is pretty inefficient; before (or in addition to) parallelizing it, fix it up to speed everything up: a) `PunctWordTokenizer()` should be initialized only once, used for each sentence. b) Use the result of `sent_tokenize()` directly: `for s in nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(...): ...`. c) construct a generator, not a list, of all words in the Enron corpus.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Why generator over list though?

Comment: A generator creates and returns its elements one at a time, while a list must be created in full before you can go on to the next step. For a large corpus, you can easily blow out your memory: bear in mind that you store each word as a string, and every string in python has about 21 bytes overhead, so your memory usage will be well over twice the size of your corpus.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use NLTK - use it for tokenization but write a simple parallel bigram calculation function yourself. You might want to consider the use of inbuilt [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) functions for this purpose. [Unigram Frequency Calculation](http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) example will explain the use of both the functions. You can extend the same to calculate bigrams.